# django oscar how to add benefit template context to catalogue view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-oscar

I added the discount to productdetailview by adding context and editing the template.

Everything works fine in Detailview but the context is not passed to catalogue view so this doesn't appear in browse.

I tried to add the same context with little change to the catalogue view but it doesn't work.

anyone have any idea?

[working detail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpdrj.png)

catalogue detail views.py

```
Benefit = get_model('offer', 'Benefit')



class ProductDetailView(DetailView):

  .
  .
  .
  def get_discounts(self):
      try:
          discounts = Benefit.objects.get(id=self.object.id )
      except:
          discounts = ''
      return discounts

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      ctx['alert_form'] = self.get_alert_form()
      ctx['has_active_alert'] = self.get_alert_status()
      ctx['benefits'] = self.get_discounts()
      return ctx
```

stock_record.html

```
<!--Added discount price-->
{% if benefits %}
<mark class="sale">Product in Sale!</mark>
{% with type=benefits.type %}
{% if type == 'Percentage' %} 
<p> Price after {{benefits.value}}% discount </p>
<p class="price_color">{{ session.price.excl_tax |percent:benefits.value|currency:session.price.currency }}</p>
{% elif type == 'Absolute' %}
<p> Price after {{benefits.value}}{{session.price.currency }} discount </p>
<p class="price_color">{{ session.price.excl_tax |subtract:benefits.value|currency:session.price.currency }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

by removing the try condition the query doesn't exist when going to product detail of product with discount

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\oscar\apps\catalogue\views.py", line 51, in get
    response = super().get(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 107, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\oscar\apps\catalogue\views.py", line 83, in get_context_data
    ctx['benefits'] = self.get_discounts()
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\oscar\apps\catalogue\views.py", line 76, in get_discounts
    discounts = Benefit.objects.get(id=self.object.id )
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\beit\Desktop\NEWSITE\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 439, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /he/shop/catalogue/u05deu05d5u05e6u05e83_3/
Exception Value: Benefit matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Possibly your `get_discounts()` method is returning ' ' from your except condition. Since in your template all the code is inside `{% if benefits %}`, if `get_discounts()` returns an empty string, the condition will fail.

Comment: HI, yes thanks, i have figured it out too but i don't know why the benefits stay empty even though i pass the context

Comment: As I said previously, possibly because the `get_discount()` function used in `ctx['benefits']` is returning an empty string. Before `{% if benefits %}`, try `{{ benefits }}` and see if it shows anything.

Comment: @NaeemKhan thanks for the reply, I understand that. but the problem is different. {{benefits}} does return empty string only in catalogue view, not in product detail view. maybe i did not understand your answer. even if i remove the if statement it will keep returning the right context on detail page but not on catalogue view

Comment: The code you have posted above only seem to have that problem. Why it is being returned empty could be one of many things. I suggest you try printing `self.object.id` to see if it is empty or not. Otherwise remove the try/catch expression and let the view throw error to see what it says.

Comment: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/views.py  - the only thing i changed in this view is written above in the question. thanks again.

Comment: @NaeemKhan added the trackback if i remove the try to the post because too long for comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `self.object.id`. As evident from the traceback which throws a DoesNotExist exception:

```
Exception Value: Benefit matching query does not exist.
```

I'm not sure where this `self.object` is coming from, but that is most likely the culprit. To test it out, you can give your `Benefits` query an ID that actually exist in your DB and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, the self.object.id is to obtain the id of the product for the discount, it is the only option to render the discount in detail view. there is no option that i know about to replace it / remove it. but you are right that the catalogview does not provide a valid object.id queryset and why this is what i am trying to figure out. my guess is like you said because the get discounts function is wrong calling the queryset. what is the right way to call benefit queryset from catalogview?

Comment: If you want to pass an object between two classes, you can send its ID from first view to the second using [URL Parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/).